# Query in Lucene

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

The structure of the table "testtable" is

1. id int primary key
2. productid int
3. attributeid int
4. value varchar(250)

where productid is the unique id of a product,
attributeid is the unique id of attribute of a product e.g. size, quality,height, color
and 'value' is the value for the attribute

i have to filter a result. I achieve the requirement by this query.
But i am not able to make it in a query.

```
select a.* from dbo.testtable a
where a.attributeId=10 and a.[Value]='Romance'
and productId in
(
    select productId
    from
    dbo.testtable where attributeId =7 and [Value]='Hindi'
)
```

Need help to build this query..

Comment: You can't query tables with lucene. Do you have an existing lucene index for this data?

Comment: Yes.. The data is already indexed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to do this in two steps:

Step 1: extract product ids

```
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();

query.add(new TermQuery("attributeId", 7), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST); 
query.add(new TermQuery("value", "hindi"), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST); 
TopDocs docs = searcher.search(query, null, searchLimit);
```

You then need to extract the productId from the docs

Step 2: run query

```
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();

query.add(new TermQuery("attributeId", 10), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST); 
query.add(new TermQuery("value", "Romance"), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST); 

// build "IN" clause
BooleanQuery pidQuery = new BooleanQuery();
for( long productId : productIds ){
    pidQuery.add(new TermQuery("productId", productId), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD); 
}
query.add(pidQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST); 
TopDocs docs = searcher.search(query, null, searchLimit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at using Hibernate Search which provides you with semantics of lucene based searching on a database. Alternatively look at luke and figure out how lucene has indexed your data. Play around with it and it will help you frame lucene queries as it gives you a deeper look into lucene indexing and searching.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am using Hibernate Search. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-Attribute-Value_model].

The requirement is to filter the data using multiple attribute.